# How to display specific number of rows from PHP query on one page and then expanding the div if the rows returned are more than the specified amount

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

**Question 1:**

I have a table called `user_thoughts`. Alice has 15 thoughts (15 rows). At the moment, each thought is processed and displayed in a div, but I want 10 thoughts or 10 rows to be displayed on one page, then the user can then, say, click a `load more` button to display the rest of the remaining thoughts.

A page should basically depict 10 thoughts per page max. I have tried the `LIMIT` clause, but later realized the `LIMIT` clause only returns the first 10 rows in the database.

**Question 2:**

If a user goes past 10 thoughts per page, the aim is to display another set of thoughts (10 new thoughts) on the page when the user reaches the bottom of the page.

This is the code which echo's a new div based on the number of rows returned by the user:

```
<div id="userposts_panel">
    echo " <div class='small' style='min-height: 150px;'>
                <div class='panel panel-default' style='margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:10px;'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>
                            <div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>
                                <span id='options' class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-flag' aria-hidden='true'></span> 
                                <span style='padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;'> | </span>
                                <span id='remove' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span> 
                            </div>
                            <img src='$profile_pic' height= '68px' style='border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;'/>
                            <span style='margin-left: 10px;'>$message_content </span> <br/> <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel-footer'>
                            <a href='profile_page/$thoughts_by'> <b> $name_of_user </b> </a> - $date_of_msg on $time_of_msg  
                            <div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' aria-hidden='true' style='padding-right: 5px;' onclick='changeIcon()' ></span> 
                                |
                                <a href='#' onclick='return toggle($thought_id);' style='padding-left: 5px;'> View comments </a> 
                            <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' style='display:none;'>
                                <br/> $comment_body
                            </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>";
?>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
function yHandler (){
    var userposts_panel = document.getElementById('userposts_panel');   
    var contentHeight = userposts_panel.offsetHeight; // get page height
    var yOffset = window.pageYoffset;// get vertical scroll position - find out where user is on scroll.
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;

     if (y >=contentHeight){ // if the user scroll to the very bottom, do this..
         userposts_panel.innerHTML += '<div class="userposts_panel"></div>'


         }
 }
    // event listner
    window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

But it does not seem to expand the div when scrolling to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called infinite scrolling. A lot of blog themes and tumblr's use it. There is a pretty good demo and tutorial of it here which loads 10 at a time exactly like you are describing: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html

It just uses pagination like you would normally but kind of secretly loads it within the same page to make it seem like one big page. You can see the url changing in the demo:

```
<a href='index.php?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
```